# How can vectors be passed by value?

Tags: c++, vector

I've been trying to understand how C++ vectors operate, but I just can't find out how they do this one thing: how can they be passed by value?

As far as I know, vectors operate using dynamic arrays, making them both fast and easy-to-use. But, if they use dynamic arrays, why can we pass them to a function by value? How does the pointer in the value passed to the function NOT point to the same place as the original vector's pointer?

I've been searching the web for an answer for a while, but all I can find is "how can I pass a vector by value" instead of "how is it possible to pass a vector by value" :(

Comment: Because `std::vector` (and any other decent container) has a copy-constructor that duplicates the data when it is passed by value.

Comment: You may also be interested in [What is move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/11082165)

Comment: *But if they use dynamic arrays, why can we pass them to a function by value?* -- You are passing them by value.  In C++, by value means that an independent *copy* is made of the passed-in value.  Are you coming from another language, like Java, C# or python, where passing objects means you are actually passing the original object and not a copy?

Comment: C++ is not a language you can learn by try and guess and by asking questions on SO. Nowadays everyone wants to shortcut whatever they can, but in the end, you'll eventually realize all the wasted time. Take the time to properly learn C++, follow courses, or get [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). If you did so, you would have the answer to this question when you'll arrive to the (copy)-constructor chapter :)

Comment: In that case, `std::vector`'s copy constructor performs the deep copy.

Comment: Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about the copy constructor.

Comment: Here's a [small example](https://godbolt.org/z/xK3ddsv38) of what happens when you pass it by value

Comment: `void foo(vector<int> v) { for (auto x : v) { cout << x << " "; } cout << "\n"; } int main() { vector<int> v{ 10, 20, 30 }; foo(v); }` Passes the vector by value, using the vector's **copy constructor**.

Comment: Because `std::vector` does **deep copy** when using **copy constructor**.

Answer (score 5):

You need to think both about implementation details and about semantics when you think about "by reference" and "by value".

In your case, you appear to think "by value" means "in automatic storage" - on the stack, or stored within an object.  And "by reference" means "on the heap, stored as a pointer".

Those are fair models.  But semantically, by value simply means that modifying the two copies doesn't interfere with each other.

Ie:

```
void foo( some_type x ) {
  modify(x);
}
some_type instance;
foo(instance);
// foo did not modify instance!
```

in this case, `some_type instance` was passed using value semantics if modifications of the value within `foo` did not modify the value `instance` outside of `foo`.

For a vector, when it is passed by value, it just means that modifications of the vector within the function don't change the vector outside.

Things get interesting when you have something like a vector of pointers (or smart pointers, or anything else with reference semantics).  Then the pointers are passed by value, but they in turn are references to common data!

In the vector's case, vector is typically implemented as 3 pointers.  The first points to the start of a buffer, the 3rd points to one-past-the-end of the buffer, and the 2nd points to somewhere in the middle.  The vector template ensures that all of the parts of the buffer between the 1st and 2nd (half-open interval) are constructed with valid objects.

When you pass a vector by value, it creates a new "large enough" buffer and copies the valid objects (between the 1st and 2nd pointer) to the new buffer.  When the new vector goes out of scope, it cleans up this new buffer.

```
void foo(std::vector<int> x) {
  for (auto& elem:x)
    elem+=7;
}
std::vector<int> instance{1,2,3,4,5};
foo(instance);
for (auto& elem:instance)
  std::cout << elem << ",";
std::cout << "\n";
```

in this program, `instance` is a vector containing 1 through 5.  We pass it *by value* to `foo`, which increments *the local copy* elements of the vector by 7.

The variable `instance` is not modified by this operation, and when we print it we get `"1,2,3,4,5,\n"`.

If we change this to passing by reference:

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& x) {
  for (auto& elem:x)
    elem+=7;
}
std::vector<int> instance{1,2,3,4,5};
foo(instance);
for (auto& elem:instance)
  std::cout << elem << ",";
std::cout << "\n";
```

we now print

```
8,9,10,11,12,
```

Here, I'm using an actual C++ reference.  We can "pass by reference" by using a pointer, or we can do it by using a `std::reference_wrapper`.  In some cases, you can "pass by reference" by using a string name of an object being looked up in a common table; I'm using "reference" here as semantics (the meaning of the code), not as the implementation detail.

By keeping semantics clear -- that you are passing by value, not reference -- you make understanding the code easier.  Passing by copy (value) makes code insanely easier to reason about; so one solution is:

```
[[nodiscard]] std::vector<int> foo(std::vector<int> x) {
  for (auto& elem:x)
    elem+=7;
  return x;
}
```

here, we take a vector by value, and we return it by value.

The caller:

```
std::vector<int> instance{1,2,3,4,5};
instance = foo(std::move(instance));
for (auto& elem:instance)
  std::cout << elem << ",";
std::cout << "\n";
```

both is prevented from forgetting to store the return value, and never has their parameters modified accidentally.

You'll sometimes hear a rule that you shouldn't mix reference and value semantics.  This can happen in a few ways.  The easiest is storing a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>` - now a value-copy of the vector still has references to shared data, and what a function can change is really hard to describe.

Another easy way is having a `struct` that mixes values and pointers, or even values and references for extra insanity.

```
struct bad {
  int x;
  double& y;
};
```

thinking about `bad`'s behavior is a mess.

```
int ione = 1, itwo = 2;
double done = 1., dtwo = 2.;
bad a {ione, done};
bad b {itwo, dtwo};
bad c = a; // c.y refers to a.y which is done
c = b; // c.y still refers to done, but now has the value 2.
```

ew.

If `y` was a pointer:

```
struct bad {
  int x;
  double* y;
};
```

we have another kind of "what is a value".  Do we think of `y` as the value of the pointer, or the value of the pointed-to?  If the first, then `bad` can have value semantics without a problem; if the second, it has mixed value and reference semantics.

Pointers are things whose value is the address or location of an external reference.  Reasoning about things that are both values and reference is often tricky, and pointers are no exception.

When you create a class like `std::vector`, while you use pointers internally, `std::vector` mostly hides that as an implementation detail.  Like all abstractions it leaks, and you can see it leaking in the rules for iterator invalidation.

But `std::vector` doesn't model a pointer to a buffer of memory with data in it.  `std::vector` models a variable sized buffer of memory with data in it; it uses value semantics.

These semantics are extended by it also being efficient to move (O(1) guarantees in some cases), and that certain move operations guarantee iterators and pointers within it to be stable.  We can contrast that with `std::string`, who does not guarantee pointer stability after the same move operations (this is because `std::string` permits the small-buffer optimization of storing the characters within itself; vector does not permit it).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but it doesn't answer my question. I want to know how the vector class can be passed by value (meaning that a change made on the parameter inside the function won't apply on the original), despite using dynamic arrays. In other words, how can I do something similar? How can I pass a dynamic array by value?

Comment: @AmirrezaNadiChaghadari You want to kniw what a copy constructor is?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that `std::vector` implements both a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator that do a "deep" copy, so when you assign or copy one, it creates a whole new copy of the contents of the vector, not just a copy of the pointer to the content of the source vector.

This means that if the vector is very large, passing it by value can and will often be quite slow, so most code will pass a reference to a const vector (`std::vector<T> const &foo`) or pass iterators, rather than passing a vector by value, unless the function does something that will require two entirely separate copies of the data anyway.

Comment: Do you mean that the vector class copies the original vector every time its constructor or assignment operator is called?
If so, why? Why not just implement a "std::vector::copy" function?

Comment: @AmirrezaNadiChaghadari: that depends. Yes, if you use its copy ctor/copy assignment, it'll make a copy of the source vector. But it also supports move assignment/move construction that doesn't (at least normally) copy the data. It does this so if you make a copy, it'll be a copy (e.g., changing it won't change the original). Not such why you'd want to call it `std::vector::copy` instead.